# Haskell: Replace a subString in a String without Data.List package

Tags: string, list, haskell, text, haskell-stack

I'm very new in Haskell and I want to know how I can replace a predetermined word in a String by another word. This is my code so far, I know I can't do this for now:

```
treat :: String -> String
treat text = text

main::IO()
main = do argv <- getArgs
          texte <- readFile "intputText"
          print (separation text)
          print ( treat text )


separation :: String -> [String]
separation [] = [""]
separation (c:cs) | c == "\Graph"  = "Graphic : " : rest
                  | c == '}'  = "" : rest
                  | c == '{'  = "" : rest
                  | otherwise = (c : head rest) : tail rest
    where rest = separation cs
```

So basically I know I can't put a String in the first c == "\Graph" so I want to know
how I can basically replace every word "\Graph" in my String *text* by "Graphic".

I want to be able to do that without importing any package.

If anyone can help me out I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Importing modules. Packages are more like libraries.

Comment: You need compare character by character, if there is match you track back and perform the substitution and restart the process of this point forward.

Comment: You only want to replace words it's easier. But your code suggests you may actually want a tokenizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
replace :: String -> String -> String-> String
replace [] token repl = []
replace str@(s:ss) token@(t:tx) repl

        -- check if first char of string equal to first char of token
        | s == t = case validateToken token str of
                Just list -> repl ++ replace list token repl
                Nothing -> s : replace ss token repl

        -- if not equal then continue recursion step
        | otherwise = s: replace ss token repl
                where
                        -- validate if token matches the following chars of the string
                        -- returns Nothing if token is not matched
                        -- returns the remaining string after the token if token is matched
                        validateToken:: String -> String -> Maybe String
                        validateToken (a:as) [] = Nothing
                        validateToken [] list = Just list
                        validateToken (a:as) (x:xs) 
                                | a == x = validateToken as xs 
                                | otherwise = Nothing

example = replace "yourString" "token" "new"
```